# I cant use Ctrl+s to save in eclipse when language is not english

Tags: 13.10, eclipse, input-language, system-language

I cant use Ctrl+s or any other shortcuts in eclipse when language is not english, is it a bug with ubuntu or eclipse ? how can i fix it? it is very annoying when i am coding in eclipse.i have recently updated to ubuntu 13.10.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

well its a know bug I guess since 13.10
on libreoffice and eclipse (and maybe other java applications ) hotkeys like ctrl-c ctrl-v ctrl-s ctrl-b and so on dont work while in foreign language
see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1246583) for example 
search for "hotkey 13.10 language" and maybe youll find a fix. I  didnt..